# Network call not happening from a thread in a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-networking

Im a beginnner of android and im trying to build an app that recognizes a missed call and sends the number to be stored in a remote mysql database. The app is able to recognize missed calls but the network calls are not happening. I am not able to run this app in the emulator and so im using a device everytime i make changes to this app.

This is my code

```
    package com.example.missedcallverify;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

    import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
    import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
    import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class IncommingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

         static boolean ring=false;
         static boolean callReceived=false;
         static String callerPhoneNumber;


         @Override
         public void onReceive(final Context mContext, Intent intent)
         {

                // Get the current Phone State
               String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

               if(state==null)
                   return;

               // If phone state "Rininging"
               if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
               {           
                         ring =true;
                        // Get the Caller's Phone Number
                        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                        callerPhoneNumber= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, callerPhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }



                // If incoming call is received
               if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
                {
                       callReceived=true;
                       Toast.makeText(mContext, callerPhoneNumber+"hello ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }


                // If phone is Idle
               if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
               {
                         // If phone was ringing(ring=true) and not received(callReceived=false) , then it is a missed call
                  if(ring==true&&callReceived==false)
                  {
                           Toast.makeText(mContext, "It was A MISSED CALL from : "+callerPhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           final Intent intnt = new Intent(mContext,
                                    MyService.class);
                            intnt.putExtra("callerPhoneNumber", callerPhoneNumber);
                            mContext.startService(intnt);

                  }
             }
      }



    }
```

MyService.java

```
package com.example.missedcallverify;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

  String callerPhoneNumber;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();


  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    callerPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(callerPhoneNumber);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new Thread(){
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
        String result = "";
        InputStream is = null;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no", callerPhoneNumber));
        try{
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.in/confirm_user.php");
              httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
              HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
              is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }       
      }
    }.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.missedcallverify"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <!-- Register the Broadcast receiver  -->
        <receiver android:name=".IncommingCallReceiver" android:enabled="true"> 
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" /> 
                </intent-filter>
           </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I get the toast saying It was a missed call from: number. However the network call is not happening and im unable to see the logs too. I dint see even service started message. Please help me

Answer (score 3):

A BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive` method is meant for short synchronous operations only - once the last line of the method is executed the context is dead. Thus any asynchronous operations you start here (e.g. background threads) will die immediately.

If you want to perform a long-term operation as a result of a broadcast you should use a service to do so. In the `onReceive` you should start your service, and the service will run those operations.

Read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) (mainly the Receiver Lifecycle bit).

Comment: I added the service. Even then it doesnt work. Is there anything wrong with my code? Please review and help me.

Comment: On a quick glance it seems ok, you need to debug and understand exactly what happens - "doesn't work" is a bit too generic for me to help you out. Does the service start? does the thread start? is there an exception somewhere?

Comment: The service does not start. I see neither the toast message nor the number updated in the database.Is calling the service also an async task which cant be done from the receiver? Do i need an activity to make it work?